# pd.fillna() not working on all numeric columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that has about 15 numeric columns, and for some reason when I pass those numeric columns as a list into the `pd.fillna()` method, 3 of them don't have their values filled, and I'm not sure why this is the case.

**MY CODE:**

```
num_cols = df.select_dtypes(include=[np.number]).columns.tolist()
```

`num_cols` then looks like this:

[image: numeric columns]

Then I pass `num_cols` into the dataframe using the `fillna` method, but some of the columns aren't affected by it.

```
df[num_cols].fillna(df[num_cols].median(), inplace=True)
df[num_cols].isnull().sum()
```

This last command produces the following picture:

[image: Sum of empty values for numeric columns]

Any idea why this wouldn't be working?

Comment: I think need `df[num_cols] = df[num_cols].fillna(df[num_cols].median())`

Comment: @jezrael I just did this, and it worked on all the columns except one, which had dtype <code>np.float16</code>, which was not the same as the others.

Comment: hmmm, interesting, what is your pandas version?